# jQuery is not defined in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

in my WordPress site jQuery Functions are not working after configure Async JavaScript plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might find this discussion helpful: [Async JavaScript Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/async-javascript-plugin/). Tl;dr: "change jquery.js config to not to be asynced (or deferred)".

Comment: How did you configure this plugin? The way you configured it might be what's causing the issue too.

Comment: Thanks for adding the configuration information, that's helpful.